# C++ Specific Node Linked List Deletion. Does the code make sense?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I need to delete a Dessert Node when a value is passed. I search the linked list, a match appears, delete the node and return true. If value isn't found I return false.

```
bool LinkedList::delNode(string flavor)
{
    Dessert *pointer1 = head;
    Dessert *ptrT;
    while (pointer1 != NULL) {
        if (pointer1->flavor != flavor) {
            ptrT = pointer1;
            pointer1 = pointer1->next;
        } else { 
            ptrT->next = pointer1->next;
            delete pointer1;
            return true; 
        // Should I add a break here ?
        } 
        else if(pointer1->next == NULL) { return false; } 
    }
}
```

I'm not entirely sure if the coding here makes sense for all the possible Node locations.

Comment: Since you asked, honestly, I'd probably [do **this** instead](http://pastebin.com/m9xcbHFQ). Less tedious and prone to errors (like  missing `return` values). Regardless, your final else-if isn't needed, but you're missing a return statement. What happens if the loop exhausts and `pointer1` reaches NULL. Or what happens when you send an empty list (null head pointer) ?

Answer (score 0):

Once you `return` from a function, no further statements will be executed, so adding `break` after `return` won't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Keep `if/ else if/ else` in proper order. Here the lase `else if` statement doesn't have a `if` statement. You may get an error

> error: 'else' without a previous 'if'

```
 if (pointer1->flavor != flavor) {
     ptrT = pointer1;
     pointer1 = pointer1->next;
 } 
 else if (pointer1->next == NULL) { return false; } 
 else { 
    ptrT->next = pointer1->next;
    delete pointer1;
    return true; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize `ptrT` pointer, if you code run into the `else` situation(just think about delete `head` node, then the program will crash.

```
bool LinkedList::delNode(string flavor)
{
    Dessert *pointer1 = head;
    Dessert *ptrT = NULL;
    while (pointer1 != NULL) {
        if (pointer1->flavor != flavor) {
            ptrT = pointer1;
            pointer1 = pointer1->next;
        }
        else if(pointer1->next == NULL) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            if (ptrT == NULL) {
                head = pointer1->next;
            }
            else {
                ptrT->next = pointer1->next;
            }
            delete pointer1;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```